# How to display objects from an observablecollection in a listbox based on a search string?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, search, listbox

Thank you for reading my question.

**The situation:**

I have an `ObservableCollection<CheckableListItem<T>> CheckableItems`

The class `CheckableListItem<T>` has 2 elements: `bool IsChecked` and `T Item`.

The class acts as a wrapper class that adds a checkbox to each Item. 
In this project the Item passed has a string element called Name.

***How it is displayed in XAML code:***

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CheckableItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This gives me a Listbox with every entry containing a checkbox and the content of the checkbox is the Item.Name string.

**The problem:**

I have added a textbox in XAML `<TextBox></TextBox>` And Now I would like the listbox to only display the objects from the observable collection which match the text from the TextBox.

**How I think it could be done:**

Create a view of some kind to bind to the listbox and update the view with only the objects that match the search criteria. If no text is entered in the searchbox then all object must be displayed, If only the letter E for example is entered, only the objects containing a letter E in the Item.Name property should be displayed.

I think best would be to bind the text to a string variable in my datacontext and fire an event each time the string changes, something like this:

```
string SearchString

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

The function:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Called each time the text changes, perform search here?
}
```

I just lack the knowledge of WPF syntax for how to create this or how to google the right terms.

**Edit:**

I now have an `ICollectionView checkableItemsView` of my `ObservableCollection<CheckableListItem<T>> CheckableItems` But how to filter it on the Item.Name property?

**The binding works, just the filtering I need help with:**

```
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckableItemView}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Any input is welcome. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than binding directly to your `ObservableCollection`, you could bind to an `ICollectionView`.

This would allow you to set a `Filter` property (using a predicate) that would filter out entries at the UI level, without changing the underlying collection.

Take a look at the filtering section of this page:
http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

edited to add example of filtering:

```
ICollectionView _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
_customerView.Filter = CustomerFilter

private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
{
    Customer customer = item as Customer;
    return customer.Name.Contains( _searchString );
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for I think, I will accept your answer when I get it working. Started reading the document now.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction but your example was a little hard from my wpf perspective to understand, So I added a link to your solution which explains it all in a simple way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Enrico's link: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/

Answer (score 1):

.After some more research I came with the following solution:

Credits go to Paul for pointing me in the right direction.

Source: http://jacobmsaylor.com/?p=1270

```
        private bool CustomFilter(object item)
        {
            CheckableListItem<Item> checkableItem = item as CheckableListItem<Item>;
            if (checkableItem != null && checkableItem.Item.Name.Contains(SearchString))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            checkableItemsView.Filter = CustomFilter;
        }
```